# resolve() executes but promise not resolves as expected

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have such code: (I put here the whole code  in order not to miss anything)

```
let updateCoverLoaded;

function coverLoaded(cover){
  clearInterval(updateCoverLoaded);  
  updateCoverLoaded = setInterval(() => coverLoaded(cover), 25);
  const coverSelector = $(`[aria-label="${cover}"]`).find("image")[0];
  return new Promise(resolve => { 
    if(typeof coverSelector !== "undefined"){
       const coverSelectorSource = coverSelector.getAttribute("xlink:href");
       if(getCoverWidth(coverSelectorSource) !== 0) {
          clearInterval(updateCoverLoaded);
          setTimeout(() => { 
              player.SetVar(`${cover}`, true);
              setTimeout(() => player.SetVar(`${cover}`, false), 100);
              resolve();
          }, 100); 
       }
    }
  });
  
  function getCoverWidth(src) {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    return image.naturalWidth;
  }
}

// Add SFX to cover entrance and exit
async function feedbackCover(){
  await coverLoaded('coverB');
  console.log('after resoving promise as expected!');
}
```

Although code reaches the `player.SetVar(`${cover}`, true);` line of code and I'm sure that `resolve()` is executed the promise doesn't resolve and I can't see `console.log('after resoving promise as expected!');` Why? it works in some other situations!

**Note:** The code actually waits for an element (an image) to load and then resolves the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible problems, the first is that if the image isn't loaded yet it the first Promise doesn't resolve and all subsequent Promises are discarded, the second is that if `coverLoaded` is called again, the first promise will never resolve.

This *should* work as expected:

```js
function coverLoaded(cover) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const updateCoverLoaded = setInterval(() => {
        const coverSelector = $(`[aria-label="${cover}"]`).find("image")[0];
        if (typeof coverSelector !== "undefined") {
          const coverSelectorSource = coverSelector.getAttribute("xlink:href");
          if (getCoverWidth(coverSelectorSource) !== 0) {
            clearInterval(updateCoverLoaded);
            setTimeout(() => {
              player.SetVar(`${cover}`, true);
              setTimeout(() => player.SetVar(`${cover}`, false), 100);
              resolve();
            }, 100);
          }
        }
    }, 25);
  });

  function getCoverWidth(src) {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    return image.naturalWidth;
  }
}

// Add SFX to cover entrance and exit
async function feedbackCover() {
  await coverLoaded("coverB");
  console.log("after resoving promise as expected!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'll test this tonight... please don't leave me alone till the expected result :)